# How to export textures applied to a mesh's faces in a texture atlas

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there a way one can combine all textures that are applied to a mesh's faces in a texture atlas in blender and export said atlas as .png alongside an .obj for example?

If not, is there a way one can map textures of a texture atlas to a mesh's faces in blender? (I believe this process might be called 'uv mapping', but how does one apply images to the unwrapped 2d image?)

Here a sample atlas:

[image]

Should any of this be possible, do you know of any tutorials that explain the process in detail?

Comment: Yes, it's called UV Unwrapping/mapping; Just look up any tutorial on Youtube.

Comment: To apply the image to a UV map, you can use baking. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15510/599