# How can I merge several UV images into one UV image?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, unity

I have created several space ships using up to 7-8 single images to texture the objects. As I am a blender beginner I did not unwrap the models and create a texture from the unwrap; instead, I just unwrapped the models and used a lot of different images on their faces.

Now that I want to use the model (I use it in Unity 3D) there are a lot of materials on the objects, one for each image I used. For mobile game performance I'd like to have one single image for each model, including all textures I used.

Is there any way to merge all used images (with their UV mapping still intact) to one big image which will be imported as one single material for the model in unity?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15740/599

Answer (score 0):

General workflow:

- Add a new UV map
- Unwrap all of your model into one texture space
- Create a new texture (empty)
- Bake your materials into that texture

If you struggle post your .blend file and I'll have a look what needs to be done.

Comment: thank you very much, I will give that a try and let you know if I need your help! :)

Comment: i tried to use texture baking but at the step of assigning texture nodes to the materials there is nothing visible on my node editor. i guess something is missing. can you maybe help me? here is a zip with an example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/69f9fk5nf01bwtu/problem.zip?dl=0