# Cycles bake with separate uv maps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking

Okay, so I was watching Andrew Price's tutorial for cycles baking ([Found Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU))
And I was wanting to do that with the floorboard addon ([More on that Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU171FTMbEk))
And the addon creates a uv layout for wood textures, but it's random for realistic rendering. Anyways, I want to bake the material, but I don't know how to do that with an object that already has a uv layout.

Comment: You want to bake to a new UV map or use the existing one?

Comment: whichever will let me keep the original look that it already has. I just want to bake the texture, not change the way the wood looks when its rendered

Comment: As long as you bake to a new image, and the existing UV map has no overlapping geometry, it should be essentially the same. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15510/599

Comment: so the uv layout is mostly outside of the image, using a lot of tiling for the wood effect. But with the cycles baking, it needs to all be in the one image

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15514/599) should work for you then, but bake combined instead of just emit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15514/599):

> A screenshot just to show how things are initially:
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Create a new UV map in *Properties > Object data*, then with it selected, edit or re-unwrap to make the second UV map layed out how
>      you want it:

In your case, *Lightmap pack* or *Smart UV unwrap* will probably do fine for the unwrap method.

> [image]
>
> 2. Create a new image to bake to by pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in the image editor, or by pressing *new* in
>      *header > Image*:
>
>    [image]
> 3. Add a texture node to your material(s), set to the image you want to bake to.

Here set the *bake type* as combined, then select the texture node and press *bake*:

[image]

> After it's baked, remember to save the image. <kbd>F3</kbd> to save it
>   to disk, or *header > image > Pack as PNG* to pack it into the .blend
>   as a png.