# How to change UV map loaded from obj when change unwrap way

Tags: uv

I import an 3D object from OBJ file, and the relative .mtl and map image are loaded automatically.

My UV map image is messy.

[image: Messy UV Map]

I want to use other unwrap way or make seam by myself. But when I use other unwrap way, only triangle mesh change, UV map is still the same, so object renders incorrectly.

[image: Use Smart UV Project]

I am not good at Blender... Is it possible to move UV map with the triangle mesh, and generate new UV map?

Thanks.

Comment: Not to sure what is happening. Is it possible you could you upload some screenshots?

Comment: I add two screenshots to describe my question.
Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: Thanks :) Still not quite sure what you want though, in your second screenshot the UV map looks different like it should. What do you mean by "only the triangle mesh changes"? The mesh itself in the 3D view?

Comment: I use another way to unwrap my model, so the triangle mesh is re-arranged. But the UV image doesn't change, so the image sticks to the wrong position(wrong mesh). I am wondering that "Is it possible to re-arrange UV Image automatically, so that image can correspond to correct mesh"

Comment: Oh, you want to re arrange the *image* to fit the new UV layout? Try this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15510/599

Comment: Yes. I want to re-arrange the image to fit the correspond mesh.
Does it also work for messy UV image in my sample?
Thanks very much. I will study how to use it.

Comment: Finally, I use Clone Brush to finish my task.

[Article](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?352509-texture-painting-from-another-uv-map-(clone)), 
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4ngVoGIj1Q)