# Bake Taxtures to one Image

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I have a mesh which has many UV maps and a lot of textures applied to it. Everything is in one material.

Is it possible to Create a final UV map And bake the textures together in one big image?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. I have the similar case as yours. I've got a model, which consists of multiple separate parts. Each part has its own single *material* and own *textures*.
[image]

First join the meshes together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
[image]

Next create a ***new UV Map*** (press the ***'+'*** button in the *UV Maps* panel of the *Mesh Data* header and *add a new image* in the *UV Editor* window.
[image]

Unwrap your mesh with <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Unwrap*.
[image]

Go to *Render* header, set the *bake mode* to ***Textures*** and hit the ***BAKE*** button. It will create one big color texture map from the all textures you've apllied.
[image]

---

***EDIT:***
Here's a case, where object has *one material* and *multiple textures* applied to each face of the cube (via Unwrap-->*Project from View(Bounds)*). Every face has its own *UV Map* slot.
[image]

I then marked seams for the cube, unwraped it and created new *UV Map* for it (called 'all'). Then baked the Textures. And here's the result:
[image]

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: In my Case its a single mesh. If you join meshes together with ctrl+j you effectively do not have a single Material anymore. Which in my case I do.

The Probelm I have is how to enable specific UV Maps for Specific Textures on one material and bake it together.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it doesn't help, please provide more information about your textures setup or maybe post your .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from UVMaps using "UV Map" node (under input in material node editor), or you can use "Atribute" node and connect vector output to texture and write UVMap name to it. 
Also check Texture Atlas which been develop for baking textures from multiple object to one. It create one object and don't change your original objects. Here you can easily make new UVMap for baking textures to it.