# One Material, Multiple Textures?

Tags: texturing, materials

Can I assign more than one texture to the same material, and then assign one of the textures to certain selected faces of an object, and assign another texture to other selected faces of that object (all faces having the same material)? Or do I have to assign different materials to these faces in order to give them different textures?

Comment: It is possible. See the edit of my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57944/bake-taxtures-to-one-image

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh