# Can I combine 2 images together for UV map?

Tags: texturing, uv

(This zombie is downloaded from somewhere else)

I have 1 zombie body, and 1 set of pants. Pants and body are in different .png diffuse texture file.

My goal is to have only 1 diffuse texture file for an entire zombie with clothes.

What do you think I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Bake Taxtures to one Image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57944/bake-taxtures-to-one-image/57946#57946)