# "Unwrapping" a texture on a model created in photoscan

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am an archaeologist with little background in blender. I'm not sure if unwrapping is what I want, so I put the word in quotes.
I have a model of a pot which I generate in photoscan with a pattern running around it. It already has a UV map, which was generated when Photoscan has generated a texture for the pot. However the texture doesn't show the band of decoration as a continuous pattern. I would like to be able to unwrap the pattern in one long strip as a 2D image, so that I could publish the flattened image. How would I do that?

Here is an illustration of what I am after, since I don't know the correct terminology.
[image: Here is a description of what I want]

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as to where exactly the problem is. [Edit] it with screenshots of the pot, of the texture created by Photoscan, what you expect to see on the texture and where, model in Edit mode. Does the mesh have UV map at all or do you want to map existing texture on the mesh which doesn't have UV map?

Comment: It already has a UV map. I think I probably am going to end up redoing the UV map from what I've read.

Comment: If you redo the UV map the texture will no longer correspond the mesh (possible to fix sometimes, but more often is very complex). If you want to make texture looking in another way than it is from Photoscan then you can create additional UV map organized as desired and bake all texture details to new image based on new UV map. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map