# Drawing Texture With Different UVMap

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, baking

I am trying n' to UV remapping a model
after remapping that I realize the position of the UV isn't same anymore...
so I wonder if I need to redraw the texture...
I suck at drawing...
so is it possible to get the older model texture to fit the new one with new UV Map?

Comment: If the mesh has that old UV map used when creating original texture then yes, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map

Comment: Owh my...,  i create the new uvmap to another mesh...,  thanks for the answer :D