# How to preview texture correctly with its UV in object mode?

Tags: texturing

I add 2 image textures and combined with mix node. Also i create 2 separated UV for each these textures. Everything works in render with no problem. It's just how can i preview selected texture correctly in object mode.

So i'm in object mode and set the viewport shader to ***solid*** and turn on **texture**. Now, in shader editor, if i click any image texture, it will be displayed in the viewport. The problem is it use the whatever current selected UV in property panel. I don't want this behaviour. I already attach UV map node and set the proper uv for each textures (and it's rendered correctly). So what i want is if i click any texture in shader editor , it should displayed with the correct UV i've attached.

Is it possible ?

video :
https://youtu.be/vUf8D8j63Ck

Comment: You should state what rendering engine you are using when asking any questions about shading. I assume Cycles. It would also be a good idea to  share screenshots of your material nodes. Have you tried Material viewport shading mode?

Comment: Hi thanks , it's already mentioned in my post, viewport shader is solid and set color to Texture (bold text). I just forgot to mention it's Blender 2.8.  I've just uploaded the small video to show that when i click the texture in shader editor, then in the property panel (right side) when i click back and forth from uv1 and uv2, the displayed image in the viewport also updated to match whatever uv i cliked. I don't want it . When i click the texture in shader editor, it should use the correct UV which i explicitly already apply using 'uv map' node.

Comment: In 2.80 it's called Look Dev instead of Material viewport shading mode.You should try that. Please mind the terminology - rendering engines and viewport shading modes are different things. If you used current version 2.79b, different things could go wrong if you use BI or Cycles in this situation. It is always a good idea to mention the render engine used that in your case could be Cycles or EEVEE even though it seems it might not be relevant in this particular instance.

Comment: That doesn't appear  to be possible with Textured shading mode in 2.79 as it doesn't use nodes in the Node editor. What you ask is generally possible with Material shading mode in 2.79 (make sure to connect output of certain node to the material output or Emit node with Node Wrangler) or LookDev in 2.8

Comment: Ok, let's make it simple: I open blender 2.79. create a plane and add image texture. Now create 2 different UV map. Set viewport shading to texture or material so you will see that texture. Now in property panel > uv map, click the 2nd uv map (just click the name, do not click the icon to make it active). You will see the texture will update as if the 2nd UV is applied. My question is why do i have that behaviour? The 2nd uv i created is not bound to the texture . The 1st UV is the active one. But why click the 2nd UV will update my texture preview ? I know it won't affect the render but why?

Comment: The second UV map is bound to object data as well as the rest of UV maps. Old viewport in 2.79 and prior used that to preview textures in Textured shading. I don't get your question now; switching UV maps just to preview them and not making them active allows to [bake from active to selected UV maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map) and use new UV mapping for new texture, in some cases it's useful.

Comment: That feature is great, but i has nothing to do with showing the selected UV on the viewport. why clicking on the uv will affect the appearance in viewport ? For those feature you said , all i need is to relayout the new uv in uv editor , add emision shader in shader editor etc and just bake (emit mode). I just can do it wihout need to preview the selected UV on viewport. So i think in this case, the UV preview on viewport is meaningless. maybe you can show me that the  preview is useful.

Answer (score 1):

- Have your image loaded as a texture
- Set your material `Base Color` to the texture you want
- With `Object Mode` in the 3D Viewport Set Viewport Shading `Color` to `Texture`

If anyone can elaborate on how to attach multiple textures to a mesh's UV that would be excellent

> !
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]