# How do I merge 3 separate "skins" into one for exporting?

Tags: export, edit-mode

I am an absolute beginner for Blender but I'm a quick learner and am having a go at this.

Essentially I am exporting 3D models from World of Warcraft to import into Tabletop Simulator (another video game). When they are exported from World of Warcraft they typically come with the model and a couple "skins" that wrap around the model, weapon, hair, etc.

(Allow me to apologize right now for not knowing the correct term for "skins")

The place I am trying to import them into, however, only allows for 1 "skin" and 1 3D model to be imported in. So, I open up Blender to see what I can do to make it 1 "skin" and when I load the model, sure enough, all the separate "skins" go right where they're supposed to be and it looks perfect. Now I just want to export it with 1 3D model and 1 "skin".

I'm sure this is more complicated than just "Oh, choose this export setting and you're done!". I'm eager to learn how to make it work!

Thank you!

Files I'm using for more context: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RlF5O02yHLNBgXSRa4rO2s1gTN5w1d0R

EDIT: Link was wrong

Comment: your screenshot shows only one texture Dwarf_body.png while you are referring to multiple ones. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Bruno - Sorry, bad link - I just updated it with the correct link which leads the the folder that it's all contained in.

Comment: Got it. In short, you need to create a single texture ("skin") that combines all the ones you have in the original (can be done in photoshop by simply assembling multiple png into one larger one). In addition, you need to also migrate the UVs to use this new single texture instead of the separate ones.

Comment: Oh really!? Ok, well I'm a photoshop wizard so that shouldn't be an issue at all. Is there a particular order they need to be assembled in? or just as "smushed" together as possible?

How do I migrate the UVs? (If this is just a tutorial lookup I can figure it out)

Comment: Actually easier: you should be able to bake the multiple original textures/UVs into a single new combined one. Check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map

Comment: Great! I'll give it a go tonight

Comment: Did you have any luck with Baking?

Comment: Not so much unfortunately - the whole process gets really heavy real quick for a newb such as myself :( I plan on trying to learn more about Blender and trying again in the future as it just may be out of my scope until I know a bit more what I'm doing.

Comment: Here is the first method I mentioned (without baking) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnFefCAeSNw