# How to bake textures that are scaled, adjusted through UV sliding, and repeated?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, baking, uv-image-editor

I have a question I've been really struggling to find the answer for! Is there a way to export materials and textures that are already scaled and adjusted using the mapping node, as well as clicking on one face of the mesh and sliding/adjusting each face to have it sit correctly on the mesh? For example, I have done all this to a building model. I adjusted the texture so that the windows do not appear on edges, I scaled and I transformed the textures and slid them into the proper spots. This texture though is only 4 windows big and it takes advantage of the mapping node. But now I need to export that as a complete repeated texture with the correct faces and adjustments I have made, so I'm wondering how I can bake those textures out and if this is going to help me with that? Please let me know! Thank you guys!

Comment: You create a new, non-overlapping, no mapping node UV map, contained in the 0-1 range, and then bake to new UV.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map .

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So should I do that for each face? I also have roughness, specular, ambient occlusion, and metallic maps.

Comment: You bake maps individually.  It's per-object (really, per-image.)  Read, then try, then play, you'll figure it out.