# Bake Texture to New UVMap (2.92)

Tags: texturing, uv

i'm trying to reproduce this answer : [Possible to bake texture to new UV map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map) in latest blender version (2.92)

The UV are baked on the texture but everything is black ( + transparency outside of the UV)
So i was wonderning, if something change in the process.

For theUVMap Camera i tried both but got the same result...

[image: Capture]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: hello, could you please pack the image(s) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Yes it's here : https://pasteall.org/media/1/e/1e8ddc98a25fa995a98a76f1c2b33352.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen to bake with the *Emit* option, it will bake what's emitted, but your object doesn't use any *Emission* node. In the linked page, the *Image Texture* is plugged into a *Viewer* node, which acts like an *Emission* node. If you want to bake the *Diffuse*, choose *Diffuse* instead, and under *Influence* only enable *Color*.

Comment: Yes exactly Thanks a lot !.