# UV unwrap changes Material thats Using uv coordinate

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, coordinates, texture-coordinates

So I made this plant and I wanted to join it into 1 object, uv unwrap it and export it with a baked texture, but the problem is when I uv unwrap it the material changes (because Im using a texture coordinate uv material).

does anyone konw how to fix it? (blender 3.0)

[image: Shader]
[image: Not uv unwraped]
[image: UV unwraped]

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map .  You need to create a new UV map and bake to that new map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, **the material does not change** when you unwrap, **it's the UV map that changes** and your material uses the default UV map of your object as a texture coordinate :

[image]

Select one of the leaves and go to UV Editing tab and you will understand :

[image]

This is the map that is used for the material now. But this is what happens when you unwrap the mesh again :

[image]

The map is completely distorted and since you only have one UV map, you just overwrote the one that your material uses, hence the unwanted change that you noticed :

[image]

To fix that, undo everything and go to the Mesh tab from the properties editor and under UV Maps click on the `+` icon to add a new UV map :

[image]

Make sure that this UV map is the one selected before you hit `Unwrap` and your original UV map would be safe.

I hope it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you!!!! It sure did help, the only thing was that when I exported the object, it used the default uvmap, which I didnt know, but then I re unwraped it and now everthings good :)