# Having trouble baking a texture from one UV map to another on Blender 2.71

Tags: uv, node-editor, texture-baking

Using Blender 2.71, I have two UV maps. One UV map is the original UV map, and the second UV map is copied from the original UV map, edited to fit a texture and is ready to bake to the first original UV map.

I followed this tutorial step by step using cycles.
[Possible to bake texture to new UV map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map)

I get an error message saying, "No valid selected objects".

This is my first time using nodes.

[image]

Comment: do you bake from the object to itself or is it selected to active?

Comment: It is selected to active.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, the problem was I had other objects set to render and not the object I was working on, I had to disable restrict render to the objects I wasn't using. At least I hope that was the issue

Comment: Nope, apparently that didn't work either, sorry

Comment: so what kind of bake are you trying to do? I only see one head object and it is completely black?

Comment: A texture from one UV to another UV, it must be completely black because Blender files don't carry image files without the image source.

Comment: Now when I try to bake to the original UV, it bakes to the second UV, not the original.

Comment: so I guess you need to select the second UV map in the UV Maps list, in the Shader Editor select the new Image Texture with a black image, and click on Bake? (don't use Selected to Active as you bake the object on itself)

Comment: That's what I do, but when I hit bake it just clones the texture from the second UV map, it doesn't bake to the original UV map I want to bake to, and no I don't have Selected to Active.

Comment: Is there any node I can add to guarantee that the second UV texture gets baked to the first blank UV? Putting a new blank image with the first UV selected is not doing it. Also I don't know how to find the Shader Editor in 2.71

Comment: it should work, it does for me, I hope someone will understand why it doesn't for you