How to Make a Texture for a Singular Mesh with Multiple Textures
Alright, so I'm still very new to Blender and only just started getting into 3D modeling. I am making a mesh for a game I'm working on, and need all of my mesh parts (excluding the plane) to be in one mesh. I know I can do this via Ctrl+J, but I have no idea how to do the second part; making all the textures into one texture and mapping them to the right spot. I'm pretty sure I have to use Smart UV Unwrapping and then Bake textures, but I get lost from there.
Is anyone able to help me out? Please let me know, thanks!


Heelo and welcome. Please make a search first before asking, possibly redundant with all these questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=one+uv
Tutorial : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map
